# CSS float div not working as supposed

Tags: css

I have a container div called main and then two divs floated left. The problem is that I need the main div background color visible (I supposed that the blue color background should be visible on the right side (300px which remains) and at the 4th row of the medium div as it is lower div than the left div). I also need both left and medium divs to automatically increase their heights on words wrapping and as you can see it does not work in the grey (middle) div.

See the http://jsfiddle.net/djqfo3we/2/

```
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="left"> dsfslfs sfsf slfjks flsdf slf s fs sdf ssdfegrerterte</div>
    <div class="middle">wfwefwef  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj ddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the floats otherwise the margins of the parent collapse and it appears that the parent has no height.

There are various techniques for clearing floats and you can find out more with a simple search

As for the text wrapping, as you have discovered long text strings won't break by themselves.

You can force a word break using `word-wrap:break-word` and leave your original text unchanged.

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;     /* quick clearfix */
}
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"> dsfslfs sfsf slfjks flsdf slf s fs sdf ssdfegrerterte</div>
    <div class="middle">wfwefwef  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj ddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a div inside the main div but at the bottom called clear:

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"> dsfslfs sfsf slfjks flsdf slf s fs sdf ssdfegrerterte</div>
  <div class="middle">wfwefwef jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj ddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Then give the class clear a style:

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

and you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/djqfo3we/4/

**EDIT:**
As others have pointed out, in order to apply a wrap so that they stay within the set width dimensions, add the style `word-wrap: break-word;` to the content you want to have wrapped.

I've applied the word-wrap to both the middle and left div within the main div.

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djqfo3we/10/

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.middle {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
background-color: gray;
}

.clear { 
    clear: both;
}

.middle, .left { 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"> dsfslfs sfsf slfjks flsdf slf s fs sdf ssdfegrerterte</div>
  <div class="middle">wfwefwef jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj ddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much, that is exactly how I wanted it to work

Comment: well, I haven't noticed that one issue remains and that is the overflow of the text in the grey div (middle). How to force it to increase the height instead of overflowing to the right?

Comment: Edited the answer and provided a new jsfiddle link.